# Database Schema For User Activity Flow

Tags: database, schema, datamodel

I am having a requirement where we have to ensure we design the database according to reporting needs as well.

User We are having a booking application where we are going to track user activity, I will be using the visualization toool (power bi) to prepare reports and dashboards.

Now, to track the user activity between the screen i need to link each of the events, for eg. home screen to pick up location selection screen (Pickup event) then to pickup and drop off location selection screen (pickup and drop off event) then to check fare display screen (check fare event) then to confirm booking screen (confirm booking event).

To link each search we are planning to provid the previous event id for eg, pickup event will unique id and previous_event_id (home_screen_id) similary for other events. This will help us to satisy few of the reporting needs.

I am having complexity in designing schema because this order of event is always not the same, so how do i link/establish relationship between them.

Any ideas on tracking this king of screen to screen activities for reporting needs?